# wordpress blank page with nginx

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx

I switched my webserver apache2 to nginx on centos 7 and now main index.php shows a blank page but wp-admin is working fine . In web console I can see 200 response. I enabled wp debug but no luck. here is my host file

```
   server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name new-site.com;
     location = /favicon.ico {
     log_not_found off;
     }
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
     location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

So many hours of googling I got solution  this is working config for me changed `include fastcgi_params;` to **`include fastcgi.conf;`**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi.conf;       
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This site is working for me: new-staging.opploans.com
Please try to clean up your browswer cache or, if you use a cdn, purge the content and try again.

Comment: many thanks . I got solution and now its working I changed config and updating the solution in my answer now